# Add CentOS host to Observium

Tags: system-monitoring

I install observium server and now I need to add CentOS client for observium server to monitor hdarray. I tried so many times but didn't work :/

can someone please let me explain the steps to process this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to find a way to add a CentOS host to Observium.

1. Install snmp in CentOS guest.
2. Map CentOS guest IP to dns name using observium server host file.
3. Add the CentOS host to observium using DNS name.